# DrayTek 2820n: LAN to LAN VPN connected, but half working

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, draytek

We have two locations, both using a DrayTek 2820n. Location 1 (L1) features a PDC, DNS, DHCP server (SBS 2008) with IP 10.1.1.2. Location 2 (L2) has a Windows 7 laptop only. Both locations are connected via a LAN to LAN VPN profile. L1 is set to Dial-In only while L2 set to Dial-Out only. Both locations are showing as connected on the VPN.

At L2 I can ping every IP address at L1. Using domains doesn't work - they don't resolve to an IP address. VoIP applications on the laptop at L2 can connect via IP to the PBX at L1 no problem. However if we manually give a local domain an IP address using the HOSTS file on the laptop, this domain is then pingable, but we can't browse to it using the browser - it pauses for 30 seconds then says "Page Cannot Be Displayed".

We don't have any other network problems - just with the DrayTek VPN. Do you know what's happening here and what needs to be done to resolve these issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: Sorry about the loose terminology but I cannot get to my 2820 Web interface from my current location....

1) Check that you have setup the remote LAN IP address and subnet masks correctly on both routers in the VPN definitions - if they are wrong you can often connect but get no proper routing or cannot get past the router onto the LAN.

2) Setting the dial-out end to be always on and do a 'ping to keep alive', specifying the remote router's LAN IP address can be helpful

3) Are you using the VPN as the default route for all traffic from the L2 (laptop only) end? This is also setup as part of the VPN definition. If so, check that the laptop's DNS settings allow it to get to a valid and accessible DNS server (or two).

4) Check your firmware version - V3.3.4.1 is notoriously buggy and users have been downgrading to 3.3.3 or skipping to [3.3.5](ftp://ftp.draytek.pl/Seria_2820/Firmware/3.3.5_BETA/) RC (use at your own risk and make sure you use the right annex A or B version)

Comment: Point #3 was the answer, thanks very much! :-) I asked DrayTek the same question (word for word) and they didn't know the answer!!!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.